# While loop not reading entire ifstream file

Tags: c++, fileinputstream

My ReadFile function is not reading my entire file. The file has lines of information each relating to one student.

The function (or the while loop perhaps) is reading the first two records and then exits the loop. It is reading everything correctly but why does it not continue reading the entire file (which has 13 records in it)?

I've tried `while(!infile.eof())` but the program doesn't even run with this.

Here is my ReadFile block:

```
void ReadFile() {// Reads data file into array

    ifstream infile;

    infile.open(cTextFileName);

    if (!infile.good()) {
        cout << "Cant find text data file!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    int status;
    //bool endOfFile = infile.eof();

    infile >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;

    while (infile) {
        infile >> gRecs[i].FirstName;
        infile >> gRecs[i].LastName;
        infile >> gRecs[i].NumSubjects;
        //cout << "ENTERED WHILE LOOP" << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < gRecs->NumSubjects; j++) {
            infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Code;
            infile >> status;

            if (status == 0) {
                gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Status == eEnrolled;
            } else if (status == 1) {
                gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Status == eProvisional;
            } else {
                gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Status == eWithdrawn;
            }


            infile >> gRecs[i].Subjects[j].Mark;

        }

        i++;
        infile >> gRecs[i].StudentNo;
    }

    gNumRecs = i;
    infile.close();
    infile.clear();

    cout << gNumRecs << " Records read!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to show how the file is formatted.  One of you input operations isn't correct and is causing the read operation, and thus the loop, to fail.

Comment: Here is the text file. https://pastebin.com/CCN59Dm9

Comment: So what happens when you debug your code?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and later assigning values. That is, change `ifstream infile; infile.open(whatever)'` to `ifstream infield(whatever);`. And that call to `infile.close()` isn't needed; the destructor will do that. And, finally, calling `infile.clear()` after you've closed the file doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; j < gRecs->NumSubjects; j++) {
```

should be

```
for (int j = 0; j < gRecs[i].NumSubjects; j++) {
```

Comment: This worked. But I don't understand why the index needs to be there. We are just looping until the number of subjects is reached.

The loop was working fine for the first 2 records but then doesnt so I'm confused

Comment: Without the index you are essentially accessing the first element of the array, which is correct for the first record, but not for the following.

Comment: In other words gRecs->NumSubjects is the same as gRecs[0].NumSubjects, so you got lucky on the first one, but after that it's wrong.

Comment: But why did the second record get stored properly?

Comment: You'd have to show us the class definitions to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best solution to this problem is to just avoid it completely.

Instead of a single function that tries to read the entire file, I would write a function that just reads a single record. Then call that function repeatedly until the entire file has been read. To fit with the way the rest of the standard library works, the function to read a single record should be named `operator>>`. It should receive a reference an `istream` and a reference to a record, and return the reference to `istream` when it's done.

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, gRec &record) {
    is >> record.FirstName;
    is >> record.LastName;
    is >> record.NumSubjects;
    for (int i=0; i<record.NumSubjects; i++) {
        is >> record.subjects[i].code;

        int raw_status;
        is >> raw_status;
        record.subject[i].status = cvt_status(raw_status);
        is >> record.mark;
    }
    return is;
}
```

Personally, I'd probably make a couple changes from there. I'd make a `Status`, `Subject` and `Schedule`, each of which defines its own `operator>>` to read itself from a file:

```
class Status {
    enum class status { enrolled, provisional, withdrawn } s;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Status &s) { 
        int i;
        is >> i;
        switch (i) { 
            case 1: s.s = status::enrolled;    break;
            case 2: s.s = status::provisional; break;
            case 3: s.s = status::withdrawn;   break;
        }
        return is;
    }
};

class Subject {
    int code;
    Status status;
    int mark;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Subject &s) { 
        return is >> s.code >> s.status >> s.mark;
    }
};

class Schedule {
    std::vector<Subject> classes;
public:
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is) {
        int num;
        is >> num;
        for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
            Subject temp;
            is >> temp;
            classes.push_back(temp);
       }
       return is;
    }
};
```

Then a record would be something like this:

```
class Record {
    std::string FirstName, LastName;
    Schedule classes;
public:
    std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Record &r) {
        return is >> r.FirstName >> r.LastName >> r.classes;
    }
};
```

And finally, reading an entire file full of student records would be something like this:

```
std::ifstream infile("filename");
std::vector<Record> records{std::istream_iterator<Record>(infile), {}};
```